# Set DBNull or DateTime value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a nullable Datetime property

> ```
>    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
> ```

While saving it to Database - datetime field want to check for null

If it is BirthDate is null save Null in Database or Datetime value.

> ```
>  var birthdate = ( BirthDate == null) ? DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(BirthDate)
> ```

Why it is throwing conversion error?

Please suggest me

### Edited

> ```
>   foreach (var subject in Subjects)
>                 {
>                     dbContext.Subjects.Add(new Subjects()
>                     {
>                         BirthDate = (subject.BirthDate == null) ? DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(subject.BirthDate)                           
>                     });
>                 }
> ```

Comment: Because you're trying to define `birthdate` as either `DBNull` or `DateTime`. Those types are not compatible. What framework are you using to save to the database? It's very unlikely you will need to manage this yourself...

Comment: I am trying it in .net 4.5 and saving it in sql server 2012. I am trying to do this to avoid "0001-01-01" in Database. In C#, if I try to convert null value to Datetime it will give you default date. So now I am checking it before saving. If null pass DBNull or Datetime.

Comment: are you  using Entity Framework or plain ADO.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following code if you are using plain ADO.Net to save to database.

```
 if(BirthDate.HasValue)
 {
    //say you have a SqlCommand object called cmd
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@birthDate", BirthDate.Value);
 }
  else  
 {
 //say you have a SqlCommand object called cmd
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@birthDate",null);
}
```

However, if you are using Entity Framework then let EF handle what to save if the value of BirthDate is null, and you should not be interfering in that by deciding whether to save DBNull.Value or not. So just get rid of the `var birthDate` logic and let EF do it's job.

**UPDATE 1**

change the line below to the one following it.

```
BirthDate = (subject.BirthDate == null) ? DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(subject.BirthDate);
```

Change to

```
BirthDate = subject.BirthDate;
```

Comment: Can you post your code that is actually updating the database? There is no need to use `var birthDate`. Just the set the entity properties and call SaveChanges method.

Comment: Let EF handle what to save if the value of BirthDate is null, and you should not be interfering in that by deciding whether to save DBNull.Value or not.

Comment: Why are you trying set it to DBNull.Value? EF takes care of that, so I am really confused what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please find the edited code above where BirthDate is System.DateTime?

Comment: Just use `BirthDate = subject.BirthDate;` in your  loop and let EF do it`s job. You don't need to bother about setting value to DBNull.Value in EF. That is why we use frameworks like EF since they handle a lot of these tasks behind-the-scene.

Comment: Thank you sunil for your help. Yes it is working. Sorry I take you all in wrong loop

Comment: Great, remember that EF does all that heavy lifting for us and we don't need to try to do it in our code.

Answer (score 4):

A DateTime and DBNull aren't comparable objects. Both sides of the `:` need to be of the same type.

Try casting to object

```
var birthdate = ( BirthDate == null) ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)Convert.ToDateTime(BirthDate);
```

Addditionally you can use `!BirthDate.HasValue` (instead of `BirthDate == null`).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but when I tried this getting error as "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.DateTime?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @user1893874 Seems to work ok for me - https://dotnetfiddle.net/o3dany - did you (object) both sides?

Comment: This is my code
"var birthdate = (BirthDate == null) ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)Convert.ToDateTime(BirthDate)"
getting same error

Comment: @user1893874 is there anything I've missed in that basic fiddle I put together?

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question about a string, but the same solution should work for a nullable DateTime, though maybe use .HasValue instead of == null:

[What in the DBNull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800929/what-in-the-dbnull/34801599#34801599)